# Can't extend (C:) partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I am trying to extend the `C:` with the unallocated space on the on the left.  I tried using a tool like EaseUS disk tool but it wasn't able to move `C:` to the left of the unallocated space.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGG7k.png]

Comment: IIRC, you cannot merge non-adjacent partitions. I googled it for a bit and didn't find any definitive solutions either.

Comment: Dante's answer here claims it can be done for dynamic disks using EaseUS Partition Master: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/20625dfc-e328-44da-8fdf-964e134c6d0b/how-to-extend-a-partition-with-a-nonadjacent-unallocated-disk-space

Comment: gparted or partedmagic are partitioning tools to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Using windows disk management tools, you can only extend `C:\` if unallocated space is immediately **after** it

There are third party tools which claim to help you do that but I haven't used them personally. The best documentation I could find for this is at this post http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000678.htm

Comment: is there a way to move the unallocated space to after it?

Comment: I personally haven't used it but this software claims to give you the ability to do that. Try at your own risk. http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000678.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using standard MBR disks and thus partitions must be contiguous. Furthermore, nomatter what kind of disk, you can only extend or shrink partitions from the end, not the beginning. Windows' disk management being relatively simplistic, won't let you do what you want.

Third party partitioning tools, such as [Paragon Partition Manager Free edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/) or various other tools included in Linux (e.g. gParted) can allow this but only with a series of workarounds:

1. First, you have to move the system reserved partition to the beginning of the disk. This should only take a few minutes
2. Then, you have to move the C: partition to the beginning of the disk, right after the reserved partition. This involves copying and rewriting the *entire* drive of data so can take a *long* time depending on your drive speed.
3. Finally, you can then extend the C: partition into the free space created after it.

Ultimately, the amount of time it takes may not be worth it for less than 0.5GB of extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Use GParted bootable ".iso". You can get it for free from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/).

Answer (score 0):

To extend C partition, your unallocated space must be on the right of the C drive, means you will need to move each partition along to the end of the free space until the free space is contiguous with C: and then you can extend C: to contain this free space.

PS: For logical drives, boot, or system volumes, you can extend the volume only into contiguous space and only if the disk can be upgraded to a dynamic disk. For other volumes, you can extend the volume into noncontiguous space, but you will be prompted to convert the disk to dynamic.
If you change the disk to dynamic, you can extend volume into noncontiguous space.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-extend-system-drive-partition-c-to-get-more/6acd8697-4292-4280-8270-049691d14598?auth=1

http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/manage-partition/increase-c-drive-partition.htm